# IE11 html5 onload function being called after button clicked

Tags: html, onload, internet-explorer-11

I am implementing a JSP page in HTML5 which should work in IE8 and IE11.

on the page I have a button :

```
<button onclick="moveItemFunc()">MoveItem</button>
```

This function works with 2 "SELECT" boxes and on the button click moves selected item from one box to another. This functionality works in IE8.

I also have an "onload" event defined :

```
  <body onload="loadObjects();">
```

Onload function populates my SELECT boxes with the original values.

Here is the problem. After the page is loaded I see 2 items in one box, select one of the items and click "MoveItem" button, which invokes "moveItemFunc" function which moves the Item to the second SELECT box. However after that the onload "loadObjects()" function is called again which restores the content of my SELECT boxes.

Strange thing is that it works perfectly fine in IE8 ( items being moved from one box to another and onload function IS NOT invoked after the button click ), but it doesn't work in IE11 ( onload function IS invoked )

UPD. I understand why "body onload="loadObjects();" is invoked. In my JS function I am updating SELECT objects i.e. changing the DOM which triggers the onload call.  Now the question is how can I bypass the call to the "onload" if I make changes to the objects on my page.

Comment: Do you have an example online that we can look at? Or perhaps some reduced code that shows the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: No, the site is behind the firewall. The issue is the call to <body onload="myFunction()"> after I click on the button defined on the page. And the button click invokes the javascript function defined in the outside JS file.

Comment: here is some reduced code 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/options.js"></script> -- onload function is defined there
</head>

 <body onload="createPageObjects();"> 

<form>
<button name="doNothing"  onclick="doNothing();">DoNothing</button> -- doNothing function is defined in options.js file
</form>
</body>
</html>

Inside options.js :
function doNothing(){
    alert("Do nothing!");
}

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you're reporting. I setup [a simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2myx8qru/4/), and tested it in Internet Explorer 11. I'm afraid without more code, it's unlikely you will find an answer to your problem. I'm curious; how do Chrome and Firefox handle the same issue?

Comment: It happens in Chrome too. I can't have FireFox.